# Cannot pull image from registry issue in kubernetes pod

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-artifact-registry

I am facing issue while pulling image from artifact registry to kubernetes pod.

I have created repository in artifact registry and i have pushed docker image with tag.

While i am trying to deploy images in kubernetes i am facing issue ErrImagePull issue.

I have tried to execute command below

```
gcloud describe pod {podname}
```

In events i am seeing below issue

```
Failed to pull image: rpc error: failed to resolve image: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden
```

Cluster pod using default service account. And i tried to provide artifact reader permission to default service account in gcp console.

But not working.
Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Artifact Registry in the same project as your GKE cluster?

Answer (score 0):

the first step is to validate the Service Account attached to the node pool of the GKE --> https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform?_ga=2.108247426.-1476124671.1589389489

That service account needs this role --> Artifact Registry Reader roles/artifactregistry.reader.

Lastly, validate the url of the image in the deployment.yaml -->

--image=LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT-ID/REPOSITORY/IMAGE:TAG

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have ensured yaml already and path is correct. and node is using default compute engine account as service account. So i tried to provide artifact reader access to that default compute engine account in gcp console. But didn’t worked.. is there any specific command to provide same access to try. @Deyvid Martinez

Comment: Hello Priyanka I suggest to check in the Cloud overview > Activity section and filter by the service account, to validate if there is any permission error

Answer (score 0):

First setup gcloud CLI in your machine and authenticate to your project in GCP using gcloud.

```
gcloud auth login 

gcloud auth activate-service-account ACCOUNT --key-file=KEY-FILE 

gcloud auth activate-service-account <svc-accnt-email> --key-file=serviceaccount.json 

gcloud auth configure-docker
```

When you are trying to configure a private repository, you need to configure an **imagePullSecret** in your pod/deployment. *GKE* doesnot directly authenticate to *GCR* using service account, you need to configure a **imagePullSecret**

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry gcr-auth-secret --docker-server=https://gcr.io  --docker-username=oauth2accesstoken --docker-password=$(gcloud auth configure-docker) --docker-email=<service-account-email> --docker-server=us.gcr.io
```

This will create a secret in default namespace. Based your namepsace, you can add `-n <namespace>` to create secret in your namespace. You can get the value of secret using below command

```
kubectl get secret gcr-auth-secret -n <namespace> -o yaml
```

Now, you need to configure your pod/deployment to use this secret to authenticate to GCE. You can do this by adding the below in your yaml

```
  containers:
  - name: <cont_name>
    image: <image>:<tag>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: gcr-auth-secret
```